Android Studio throws errors about AndroidVirtualizationFramework, pulseaudio, gRPC authentication, and QEMU threading issues
I use WSL on my windows 11 laptop. Trying to launch android studio emulator in VS Code but it only works until I see the google logo.
Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): 
AndroidVirtualizationFramework WARNING: 
cannnot unmap ptr 0x7f10f5e20000 as it is in the protected range from 0x7f10f5e20000 to 0x7f1176020000 WARNING: 
cannnot unmap ptr 0x7f1176001000 as it is in the protected range from 0x7f10f5e20000 to 0x7f1176020000 pulseaudio: 
Wrong context state pulseaudio: 
Reason: 
Timeout pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA context
WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port 
WARNING | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio *** 
ERROR | detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'. No response for 15311 ms 
ERROR | detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU3 thread'. No response for 16457 ms 
ERROR | detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU0 thread'. No response for 16063 ms 
ERROR | detected a hanging thread..

I already tried cold booting and only using Software but no luck.
Would appreciate all the help. Thank you guys!
